# Is it possible to avoid calling a superconstructor by default in Dart?

Tags: constructor, dart

So for instance:

```
class ButtonComponent extends Component {
  ButtonComponent(template, element) : super(template, element);
}
```

works fine. However, when I do this:

```
class ButtonComponent extends Component {
  ButtonComponent(template, element) => new SomeOtherClass();
}
```

it complains that a super constructor was called with the wrong number of attributes. Any workaround this?

In general, as you can see, I simply need to return an instance of some other unrelated class while actually using the constructor of `ButtonComponent`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have tout use a [factory constructor](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/idiomatic-dart/#factory-constructors) to do that.

```dart
class ButtonComponent extends Component {
  factory ButtonComponent(template, element) => new SomeOtherClass();
}
```